# Decrease memory usage of dynamically added controls

Tags: c#, .net, memory, picturebox

I have the following code that add images from file to Windows Forms Panel Control.

```
private void AddImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AddImageFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(AddImageFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
                AddImage(new Bitmap(memoryStream));
            }
        }
    }

private void AddImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        var pictureBox = new PictureBox();

        pictureBox.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        pictureBox.Image = image;
        pictureBox.Width = 40;
        pictureBox.Height = 40;
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pictureBox.Click += OnImageClicked;

        ImagePanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }
```

1) When I run my app, memory usage is about 18 MB.

2) When I open a FileDialog window, memory usage is about 50MB.

3) With every image that I add, memory increased by 2-10MB.

So if I add 20 images, memory usage is over 100MB.

I feel that I do something wrong, but I can't get what exactly. Could you help me to find my mistake and explain why the problem exists, please?

**Update 0**

I partially fix the problem by copy source big Bitmap to new Bitmap 40x40px and call big Bitmap Dispose(). But my app still using about 50 mb of memory. I think that the source of a problem is FileDialog. It eats memory.

Comment: Loading and holding onto images isn't free.  What did you expect?

Comment: You might try closing your `MemoryStream memoryStream` after you add the image.

Comment: @DanSchnau You have to keep the MemoryStream open according to the docs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanSchnau I have tried to use memoryStream.Close(); after add the image, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @MickyD I have found the solution described in Update 0. Do you know a way better?

Comment: @pepeevich Are you using an OpenFileDialog to select the bitmaps? If you are, is it being disposed correctly?

Comment: @pepeevich  You are using a FileStream, a BinaryReader and a MemoryStream just to load an image. You don't need any of those. You just need something like `using (Bitmap bmpTemp = new Bitmap(FileName, true)) { PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
}`  where `FileName` is the file returned by the DialogBox.

Comment: @MoonMoo Yes, I Dispose the OpenFileDialog. Some memory realeases, however, it isn't 18MB at start. Looks like 18 MB > Open Dialog > 50MB > CloseDialog > ~25 MB. I close and Dispose all streams and Dispose the FileDialog.

Comment: @pepeevich It may be worth running a memory profiler against your app so that you can see which objects are in memory. That way you can satisfy yourself that you have done all you can.

Comment: @MoonMoo Okay, ty. Could you please post an answer with reference to Update 0? I haven't enough reputation to do it.

Comment: @pepeevich You should be able to answer as you have more than 15 reputation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed with **Update 0**. Look it.

Comment: This isnt a fix, youve just blamed an underlying component. Have you created a new app with only a fileopendialog to see if that is the issue?